# Converting a list to multiple data frames, to be able to convert only a column of each data frame to numeric data

Tags: r, list, loops, dataframe

I'm new in programming in R, and I've been having this problem for several days now. I started with a list I created from splitting a file. This list contains lots of data frames. I was able to perform some operations in them, like replacing some data to `NA` with `lapply`. But right now, I got stuck and don't know how to convert only a column of this data frames inside of this huge list.

This is an example of what I have in my file:

```
d1 <- data.frame(foo = c("a", "b", "c", "d", "e"), bar = as.character(c(4.27, 5.68, 5.52, 5.20, 3.67)))
d2 <- data.frame(bla = c("a", "e", "c"), blu = as.character(c(10.14, 9.88, 10.01)))
d3 <- data.frame(lol = c("p", "s", "q", "r"), pum = as.character(c(5.96, 1.22, -1.61, 5.05)))
d1[, 2] <- as.character(d1[, 2])
d2[, 2] <- as.character(d2[, 2])
d3[, 2] <- as.character(d3[, 2])
file <- list(d1, d2, d3)
```

Which yields something like this:

```
[[1]]
 foo  bar
1   a 4.27
2   b 5.68
3   c 5.52
4   d  5.2
5   e 3.67

[[2]]
 bla   blu
1   a 10.14
2   e  9.88
3   c 10.01

[[3]]
 lol   pum
1   p  5.96
2   s  1.22
3   q -1.61
4   r  5.05
```

I would like to have as a result this:

```
[[1]]
 foo  bar
5   e 3.67
1   a 4.27
4   d  5.2
3   c 5.52
2   b 5.68

[[2]]
 bla   blu
2   e  9.88
3   c 10.01
1   a 10.14

[[3]]
 lol   pum
3   q -1.61
2   s  1.22
4   r  5.05
1   p  5.96
```

After this is ordered, I will have to extract a specific row on each of the data frames, but I guess if I understand how to perform this operation, I might be able to do this.

After a lot of trying, and finding a thread here, I was finally able to do this:

```
for(i in 1:length(names(file))){
    assign(paste("df", i, sep = ""), file[[i]])
    }
```

This piece of code let me separate the data frames I had after using the `split` function. Now I want to add inside this `for` loop, a way to reconvert the character data I have in one column to numeric data. I have tried to use a code like this inside the `for` loop:

```
df[, 2] <- sapply(df[,2], as.numeric)
```

But I get an error: 'Closure' type object is not a subset.

Anyone can help? If anyone can tell me a simpler alternative (if there is) it will be very welcome.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you want

```
lapply(file, function(x) {
    x[[2]] <- as.numeric(x[[2]])        
    x[order(x[[2]]), ]
})
```

Explained:

- `lapply` iterates a function over a list
- `file` is your list, the one we are operating on
- `function(x)` is an "anonymous" function, where `x` will be each individual element of `file`
- `x[[2]] <- as.numeric(x[[2]])` converts the second column to numeric
- `x[order(x[[2]]), ]` orders the rows of the data frame by the second column.

Comment: Let me try it first, I changed the rnorm with non random data if you want to verify it. Would you mind explaining what your piece of code does so I can understand it better?

Comment: Sure, I added an explanation

Comment: Thank you! I needed to change a bit your code because it's ordering before changing the column to numeric, but now I understand it!